# I need help figuring out why my clear button code does not work

Tags: java

I am working on a project for my Java class and cannot get my clear button to work. More specifically, I am having an issue implementing Action and ItemListeners. My understanding is that I need to use ActionListener for my clear button, but I need to use ItemListener for my ComboBoxes. I am very new to Java and this is an intro class. I haven't even begun to code the submit button and ComboBoxes and am a little overwhelmed. For now, I could use help figuring out why my clear function will not work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my updated code after suggestions:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class cousinsTree extends JApplet

{
Container Panel;
JButton submitButton;
JButton clearButton;
JTextField firstName;
JTextField lastName;
JTextField Address;
JTextField City;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JTextField Total;
JComboBox Service;
JComboBox howOften;
JComboBox numTrees;
LayoutManager setLayout;
String[] TreeList;
String[] numList;
String[] oftenList;


@Override
public void init()
{
    Panel = getContentPane();
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    TreeList= new String[3];
    TreeList [0] = "Trim";
    TreeList [1] = "Chemical Spray";
    TreeList [2] = "Injection";
    numList = new String[3];
    numList [0] = "0-5";
    numList [1] = "6-10";
    numList [2] = "11 >";
    oftenList = new String[3];
    oftenList [0] = "Monthly";
    oftenList [1] = "Quarterly";
    oftenList [2] = "Annually";     
    Panel.setBackground (Color.green);
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    submitButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    clearButton.addActionListener(new clrButton());
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    firstName = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
    lastName = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    Address = new JTextField("", 15);
    JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Address");
    City = new JTextField("Columbus", 10);
    JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");
    Total = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total");

    //Service = new TextField("Service (Trim, Chemical Spray, or Injection).", 20);
    JLabel lblService = new JLabel("Service");
    Service=new JComboBox(TreeList);

    JLabel lblhowOften = new JLabel("How often?");
    howOften = new JComboBox(oftenList);

    JLabel lblnumTrees = new JLabel("Number of Trees");
    numTrees = new JComboBox(numList);

/* Configuration */
    //add items to panel
    Panel.add(lblFirstName);
    Panel.add(firstName);
Panel.add(lblLastName);
    Panel.add(lastName);
    Panel.add(lblAddress);
    Panel.add(Address);
    Panel.add(lblCity);
    Panel.add(City);
    Panel.add(lblnumTrees);
    Panel.add(numTrees);
    Panel.add(lblService);
    Panel.add(Service);
    Panel.add(lblhowOften);
    Panel.add(howOften);
    Panel.add(submitButton);
    Panel.add(clearButton);
    Panel.add(lblTotal);
    Panel.add(Total);

    this.setSize(new Dimension(375, 275));
    this.setLocation(0,0);

Service.setSelectedIndex (1);
howOften.setSelectedIndex (1);
numTrees.setSelectedIndex (1);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File", true);
            menuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            menuFile.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuFile);

        JMenu menuSave = new JMenu("Save", true);
            menuSave.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            menuSave.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuSave);

        JMenu menuExit = new JMenu("Exit", true);
            menuExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
            menuExit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuExit);
}
class clrButton implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // clearButton.addActionListener(this);

     firstName.setText("");
     lastName.setText("");
     Address.setText("");
     City.setText("");           
}
}
class subButton implements ItemListener { 
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
submitButton.addItemListener(this);
Service.addItemListener(this);
numTrees.addItemListener(this);
howOften.addItemListener(this);
}
}
}
```

I was able to get it to work...Thank you all for your help. I removed the class and it worked.
Here is the working code:

[Code]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class cousinsTree extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
Container Panel;
JButton submitButton;
JButton clearButton;
JTextField firstName;
JTextField lastName;
JTextField Address;
JTextField City;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JTextField Total;
JComboBox Service;
JComboBox howOften;
JComboBox numTrees;
LayoutManager setLayout;
String[] TreeList;
String[] numList;
String[] oftenList;

public void init()
{
    Panel = getContentPane();
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    TreeList= new String[3];
    TreeList [0] = "Trim";
    TreeList [1] = "Chemical Spray";
    TreeList [2] = "Injection";
    numList = new String[3];
    numList [0] = "0-5";
    numList [1] = "6-10";
    numList [2] = "11 >";
    oftenList = new String[3];
    oftenList [0] = "Monthly";
    oftenList [1] = "Quarterly";
    oftenList [2] = "Annually";     
    Panel.setBackground (Color.green);
    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    submitButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    clearButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    firstName = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
    lastName = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    Address = new JTextField("", 15);
    JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Address");
    City = new JTextField("Columbus", 10);
    JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");
    Total = new JTextField("", 10);
    JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total");

    //Service = new TextField("Service (Trim, Chemical Spray, or Injection).", 20);
    JLabel lblService = new JLabel("Service");
    Service=new JComboBox(TreeList);

    JLabel lblhowOften = new JLabel("How often?");
    howOften = new JComboBox(oftenList);

    JLabel lblnumTrees = new JLabel("Number of Trees");
    numTrees = new JComboBox(numList);

/* Configuration */
    //add items to panel
    Panel.add(lblFirstName);
    Panel.add(firstName);
Panel.add(lblLastName);
    Panel.add(lastName);
    Panel.add(lblAddress);
    Panel.add(Address);
    Panel.add(lblCity);
    Panel.add(City);
    Panel.add(lblnumTrees);
    Panel.add(numTrees);
    Panel.add(lblService);
    Panel.add(Service);
    Panel.add(lblhowOften);
    Panel.add(howOften);
    Panel.add(submitButton);
    Panel.add(clearButton);
    Panel.add(lblTotal);
    Panel.add(Total);



    this.setSize(new Dimension(375, 275));
    this.setLocation(0,0);

Service.setSelectedIndex (1);
howOften.setSelectedIndex (1);
numTrees.setSelectedIndex (1);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File", true);
            menuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            menuFile.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuFile);

        JMenu menuSave = new JMenu("Save", true);
            menuSave.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            menuSave.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuSave);

        JMenu menuExit = new JMenu("Exit", true);
            menuExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
            menuExit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
            menuBar.add(menuExit);


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == clearButton) {

     firstName.setText("");
     lastName.setText("");
     Address.setText("");
     City.setText("");           
}
}

}
```

[/Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing good. But just place the following code

```
clearButton.addActionListener(new clrButton());
```

Before and outside of class `clrButton`

Also try placing these statements outside of class `subButton`

```
submitButton.addItemListener(new subButton());
Service.addItemListener(new anotherClass());
numTrees.addItemListener(new anotherClass());
howOften.addItemListener(new anotherClass());
```

Comment: Where would I implement the ItemListener at? It gives me an error since ItemListener is not extended, except under subButton.

Comment: Create classes for action events which implements ItemListener.
then add element.addItemListener(new className());

Comment: Thank you. One more question...when I insert that, the class name results in an error. When I move my bracket to include the class in init(), the error is removed, but the applet does not initialize. Any idea?

Comment: incompatible types: clrButton cannot be converted to ActionListener

Comment: Your class cousinsTree is not implementing ActionListener interface.Check

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I edited my original post to show my working code. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3076816 If It works. You should upvote or even mark my answer correct. I helped you untill it works. :)

Comment: I didn't use this for it to work but you helped me take a closer look. Thank you.  Very appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add following line

```
  clearButton.addActionListener(new clrButton());
```

---

```
class clrButton implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  //  clearButton.addActionListener(this); Comment it

  // if(e.getSource() == clearButton){-> this line don't need.

     firstName.setText("");
     lastName.setText("");
     Address.setText("");
     City.setText("");            
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies. I have tried each suggestion and this is the only one that didn't give me any errors. However, now the applet will not initialize. I will edit my post with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add actionlistener to your buttons. so, the action events will be propogated to the listener where you do your logic of the action. so, you have to addActionListener to your button

```
clearButton.addActionListener(new clrButton());
```

i.e in your `init()` method

```
clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
clearButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
//add this below line to add action listener to the button
clearButton.addActionListener(new clrButton());
```

Onemore line to be removed is `clearButton.addActionListener(this);` from your action performed method